# How add an item template to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Let me elaborate, since the title was a little rough. I have been looking for a way to make a WCF service work with Silverlight for days now. Eventually I come across a mention of something called a 'Silverlight-enabled WCF service'. The only problem is, this doesn't exist in my Visual Studio 2010 (and I have looked).

Someone then asked me whether it appears in Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Silverlight\1033. Well it looks to be - there is a file called SLWcfService.zip.

Assuming this is the template I'm looking for, how do I get Visual Studio to add this to the list of item templates that I get when I select a new project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t about your specific case, but if you have an item up on VS and you want to save it as a template: Click on: File -> Export Template -> and then select *Item* Template.